# Send Mail to different users where E-Mail-Adresses are from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to fetch all rows from a table with a condition and then send an E-Mail to the assigned User. There are 2 users in the table. If i put a sql statement in an sql statement it does not work, only the first user gets mails and mails. I am sure this is easy but I am php and mysql beginner, so please help me out.

There are 2 users in the table.

```
<?php 
require'../includes/database.php'; 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users";  
$result = $conn->query($sql);  

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  

    // output data of each row  
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $fname = $row["fname"];  
        $nname = $row["lname"];  
        $mailadresse = $row["email"];  
        $user2 = $fname." ".$nname;  
        echo $user2;  

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM iks_open, users WHERE Datum <= '$neudate' AND  pverantwortung = '$user2'";  
        $result = $conn->query($sql);  

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  
            $mailhost       = "$server";  //SMTP Host name  
            $mailsmtpauth   = true;  
            $mailusername   = "$user"; // SMTP Login  
            $mailpassword   = "$pass"; // SMTP Password  


            require_once('../includes/Mailer/class.phpmailer.php');  
            require_once('../includes/Mailer/class.smtp.php');  


            $mail = new PHPMailer();   

            $mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->Host       = $mailhost;  
            $mail->Port       = $port;  
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; // Kann man zu debug Zwecken aktivieren  
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
            $mail->Username   = $mailusername;  
            $mail->Password   = $mailpassword;  
            $mail->SMTPSecure = $sec;  


            $frommail = "$email";  
            $mail->SetFrom($frommail, 'IKS-System');  

            $address = "$mailadresse";  
            $mail->AddAddress($address);  

            $mail->Subject = "Offene IKS-Aufgaben";  
            $mail->Body = "Sie haben offene Aufgaben. Bitte einloggen und erledigen";  

            if(!$mail->Send()) {  

            $lcontact = 1;  
            } else {  
            $lcontact = 2;  

            }  

            }else {  
                echo "Alles gut";  
            }  

    }  
}  


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting **$result** variable in while statement. Be carefull with your variables and you won't have trouble like that.

Comment: if you detect the problem source, try to give a snnipet of code solution . that would be easy for the OP .

Comment: Yes you're right but there's no need for this. It's not logical problem. He have to rename his variable. I think he can do it without an example.

Comment: Anyway, before seeing your answer, I prepared that for him.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the database fetching happening inside the while loop, is overwriting the $result object.

Try this

```
<?php 
require'../includes/database.php'; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";  
$result = $conn->query($sql);  

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {  

// output data of each row  
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
    $fname = $row["fname"];  
    $nname = $row["lname"];  
    $mailadresse = $row["email"];  
    $user2 = $fname." ".$nname;  
    echo $user2;  

    $query = "SELECT * FROM iks_open, users WHERE Datum <= '$neudate' AND  pverantwortung = '$user2'";  
    $details = $conn->query($sql);  

    if ($details->num_rows > 0) {  
        $mailhost       = "$server";  //SMTP Host name  
        $mailsmtpauth   = true;  
        $mailusername   = "$user"; // SMTP Login  
        $mailpassword   = "$pass"; // SMTP Password  


        require_once('../includes/Mailer/class.phpmailer.php');  
        require_once('../includes/Mailer/class.smtp.php');  


        $mail = new PHPMailer();   

        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->Host       = $mailhost;  
        $mail->Port       = $port;  
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1; // Kann man zu debug Zwecken aktivieren  
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;  
        $mail->Username   = $mailusername;  
        $mail->Password   = $mailpassword;  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = $sec;  


        $frommail = "$email";  
        $mail->SetFrom($frommail, 'IKS-System');  

        $address = "$mailadresse";  
        $mail->AddAddress($address);  

        $mail->Subject = "Offene IKS-Aufgaben";  
        $mail->Body = "Sie haben offene Aufgaben. Bitte einloggen und erledigen";  

        if(!$mail->Send()) {  

        $lcontact = 1;  
        } else {  
        $lcontact = 2;  

        }  

        }else {  
            echo "Alles gut";  
        }  

}
```

}

?>